# Worldbuilding (Merge) Conflicts. Pseudo-Science behind Psychic Barriers?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics

I am trying to tie together my mythos with a relatively consistent set of psychic powers, but I'm starting to think that may not be possible. I'd like to preface this by saying that I intend to incorporate as many of the pulp fiction stock psychic powers as possible as a sort of general toolkit that all of my characters have access to, at least in part, varying by their personality. They are also entitled to more personal, intricate expressions of psychic power, the upper echelons of which are basically magic (psychic powers, in general, are basically magic, but you should probably get what I mean).

In a draft of my first story, the most basic utility a psychic is entitled to is the ability to project a psychic barrier, which violently rejects intruders (which can be taken to mean speeding cars and bullets). In one instance, a character has a large statue hurled toward him like a spear and his barrier pulverizes it.

**I never thought about the science behind this when I deemed it so, and I'd like it if anyone could give me some suggestions about how to explain it. I don't think it has to be explained, but I would love to do it. I think things like that are cool. As a rule, the larger the barrier is the weaker its defenses. It seems to be some sort of physical phenomenon, and I don't really understand how it works.**

I thought about replacing it with a trip-mine type defense; something like, "the psychic automatically redirects the directional vectors of an object that crosses this certain perimeter," but I don't know if I like that explanation all that much. Additionally, there have been a few scenes wherein various characters induce abstract psychic phenomena, and I've noted that during these moments, their barrier's defensive functions are turned off: the implication being that the barrier has been converted into the foundation of these effects. I'm not married to them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help here. After all, magic is magic, and "redirecting the (speed) directional vectors" is already a possible -and more than passable- simili-physics definition of the effect "rejecting intruders". Also, it's very creatively dependent of what you want, especially when looking at the seams and the causes. In other words, since physics cannot define the details of magic or its causes, what goals can you give to make an answer better for you than another?

Comment: Science can effectively be used to explain the physics behind a technologically created force-field - or it could if they existed (#1). Explaining a psychic power version would be a double whammy - we don't have force-fields or the technology to make them, so can't explain that - then explaining the psychic version adds a layer of inexplicability. The only way this could be explained through sciency-sounding words would be a sort of hybrid spiritual-technobabble which would not fall within the remit of the site I'm afraid. (#1) Magnetic effects exist, but they're limited by materials and power

Comment: We don't have force-fields or the technology to make them, so can't explain that - then explaining the psychic version adds a layer of inexplicability. The only way this could be explained through sciency-sounding words would be a sort of hybrid spiritual-technobabble which would not fall within the remit of the site.

Comment: Angry Muppet is on to what I'm after @Tortliena. I'm basically asking for a scientific explanation behind the projection of forcefields. The reason I'd like to stray away from redirecting vectors is that I wanted the barrier to be (or behave like) a physical wall. But as Angry Muppet said, there's an issue with explaining forcefields. I guess it's the same issue as explaining telekinesis with science; it's such a fanciful power that there's only so much you can do. I'm open to any ideas, but if it can't be done, it can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

**Pressure**

[image]

As you say, the field is not *always on*. It only starts pushing when it detects an intruder. In that case it pushes outwards like a balloon which suddenly has more air pumped into it.

The amount of *air* pumped into the field is based on the strength of the owner. The field pushes outward evenly at all points of the field. That means a field with twice the surface area pushes half as hard.

When activated the field pushes against the statue thrown at you. It also blows nearby pedestrians off their feet and throws up a dust cloud. It might create a temporary vacuum pocket with associated thunderclap.

So a small field that coats the body might deflect bullets but it will also pulverise anything near your skin. A large field will push bystanders more gently but bullets go straight through. If you want to push a big rock and you can mould your forcefield around the surface of the rock, then it doesn't matter if you make a big field or a small field. The net force is the same.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. Although, it sort of brings to mind another issue with the barriers that I had forgotten to put in my original post. (Should I make a new question?) That being: if the barrier can be adequately suppressed to the size of your skin and in doing so, gains efficacy, what is the point of expanding it at all once you learn to compress it? The only thing I could think of would be "protecting your organs from being throttled".

Comment: @F.Halima A good rule of thumb with magic systems is more powerful and/or precise spells are harder to pull off. A barrier that coats your skin takes more effort and concentration to create and to move around as you move around your arms and legs. You need to pay attention to stop the barrier trying to repel (ie explode off) your fingers and toes as you move them. It is much easier to have a spherical barrier follow you around.

Comment: @F.Halima The big barrier can also be thicker and gradually slow down bullets as they pass through. The hair-thickness barrier will instantly explode the bullets into shrapnel that hits bystanders. It also creates sonic booms whenever a leaf drifts too close to your body.

Answer (score 1):

## Möbius wormhole

A möbius strip is an object with only a single side. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip

A möbius wormhole is much the same. It is a wormhole with only one side. If you enter anything into the wormhole it'll come out of the exact same spot. In effect that means an object hits itself with equal force the other way. If you throw a spear the tip will hit itself with that force, probably splintering itself in the process. Or a car driving into it would hit itself as well.

I'll leave the conundrum if the resulting power is equal or double to other people. In effect you have a perfect shield. Anything coming in is always met with an exact equal opposite force. Itself. It can never pass the wormhole.

If the wormhole is projected bigger it'll get more porous. It isn't triggered everywhere, meaning molecules get past it. That means if half gets past and half is rejected, it'll look like half the power was applied.

This can be further augmented by trigger sensitivity. The wormhole could only be triggered from a certain amount of force. Air gets through, but a spear isn't. If the wormhole barrier is made bigger it can be more difficult to trigger, possibly also fluctuating between sensitivities. This makes it very reliable if small, but bigger versions can fail completely or partially. It'll maybe look more violent as parts of an object pass the barrier while others are forcefully rejected, but increases the danger to the user by a lot.

To prevent from condensing yhe wormhole to only the skin it'll be hard to make shapes with the wormhole. At most a few simple shapes can be made.